# What is "M.O.B."?

Tags: word-meaning, acronyms

What is "M.O.B."? From Hemingway's *A Farewell to Arms*

> Now let's go up the mountain. Should we? Can we get **the M.O.B.**?

Comment: Judging by the text, it appears to be a reference to a train. https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.209262/2015.209262.A-_djvu.txt  
(**‘All right. We’ll go there.’ 
? Can we get the M.O.B.?’ 
‘There’s a train a little after five.’**)

Comment: They have gone from Italy to Switzerland. The MOB is a Swiss railway, the **Montreux Oberland Bernois** Railway.

Comment: Due to an OCR error, 'Bernois' appears as 'Bemois' in the Gutenberg edition. In fact the text is sprinkled with them.